# How to remove or hide Main Menu from End-User ? XtraReports Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, report

I need to remove or hide the main menu and Layout tool bar from Report Designer of End-user. I have code to remove or hide a particular control

```
designForm.ActiveDesignPanel.SetCommandVisibility(ReportCommand.OpenFile, DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner.CommandVisibility.None);
```

but I need to hide that entire Main Menu and Layout tool bar ? How to hide this Main Menu & Tool Bar ??

[image]

Thanks in advance.
Sri

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize end user designer in detail then rather then hiding and removing panels you should use latest devexpress release with end user customization feature.
In this you can control every thing from your visual studio solution only no need to write any logic to hide or remove.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2553